# Gujrati Text return as a question mark

Tags: php, api

I am trying to develop simple application with database connectivity and there is some gujarati text in my application which retrieve from database.

I have a simple database with Gujarati data
but when i call my api at that time gujarati text retrun as a "??" sign

Here is my php file

```
<? php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    if(!isset($_POST['id'])){

    echo"Story ID is required";

    }
    else{


    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","******","*******","1275627")or die(mysqli_connect_error());

    $sq="SELECT * FROM tbl_stories WHERE id = '$_POST[id]'";

    $result_array=mysqli_query($link,$sq);

    $i=0;
    foreach($result_array as $ra){
    $data["data"][$i]["id"]=$ra["id"];
    $data["data"][$i]["title"]=$ra["title"];
    $data["data"][$i]["story"]=$ra["story"];
    $data["data"][$i]["language_id"]=$ra["language_id"];

    $i++;
    }


    $data["result"]="success";
    $data["count"]=$i;
    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($data);
    }
    }else{
    echo"Method must be POST";
    }
    exit;
?>
```

Here is my output

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "5",
        "title": "Guj",
        "story": "???? ??????? ????? ",
        "language_id": "1"
    }
],
"result": "success",
"count": 1}
```

I have tried to put

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

but doesn't work for me
Help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this 2 step

(1) change database, table and table field collection to utf8mb4_bin

(2) use database connection character set utf8mb4_bin

e.g

**For mysqli connection**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8mb4_bin");
```

**For pdo connection**

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8mb4_bin", $user, $pass)
```

Comment: Still issue remain same

Comment: you have followed step 1

Comment: Please,insert new record after followed this two step and try to get this record